# What would this code look like?

Tags: java, loops, counter

"Initialize an integer loop counter to 14, then write a while loop that executes while the loop counter is greater or equal to 6. Inside the body of the loop print the loop counter followed by a comma, using System.out.print(). At the end of the body decrement the loop counter. Outside (and after) the loop, terminate the line with an empty `System.out.println()`. "

This is what I wrote and it doesn't work.

```
loopCounter =1;

while (LoopCounter >= 6 && LoopCounter <= 14)
{
    System.out.print(LoopCounter + ",");        
    LoopCounter ++;
}

System.out.println();
```

Comment: It would probably be indented somewhere.

Comment: @hexafraction my apologies I'd forgotten to add what I had written so far.

Comment: `++` is not the decrement operator.

Comment: Where is the "initialize" part?

Comment: Where is `LoopCounter` initialized?

Comment: Looks pretty good; did you initialize the variable to 14 ?

Comment: increment = add 1, ++, decrement = subtract 1, --.

Comment: The instructions say on the first line 'Initialize an integer loop counter to 14", you initialized it to 1 so even if you got things to work you wouldn't be following the assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    int counter = 14;
    while(counter >= 6)
    {
        System.out.print(counter + ",");
        counter--;
    }
    System.out.println();
```

Comment: Can you explain how this is substantively different from my answer? It currently looks like a variable rename and nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

You don't understand the spirit of the initialization. You set the starting condition outside the loop, then only check the ending condition.

```
int loopCtr=14; //initialize the counter to 14
while(loopCtr>=6){ //while loop
    System.out.print(loopCtr + ",");    
    loopCtr--;
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: @SJuan76 Old edit and my ignorance; please reload the page